# FluentD fails to write log in Elasticsearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, openshift, fluentd

Using:

- fluentd 1.11.2
- fluent-plugin-elasticsearch 4.1.3
- elasticsearch 7.5.1
- springboot 2.3.3

Running in Openshift (Kubernetes v1.17.1+20ba474).

Both Fluentd and Elasticsearch are running in different pods.

Fluentd configuration file:

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>
<filter *.**>
      @type parser
      key_name log
      reserve_data true
      <parse>
        @type none
      </parse>
</filter>
<match *.**>
  @type copy
<store>
    @type elasticsearch
    host elasticdb
    port 9200
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix applogs
    logstash_dateformat %Y%m%d
    include_tag_key true
    type_name app_log
    tag_key @log_name
    flush_interval 1s
    user elastic
    password changeme
  </store>
  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>
```

From a local springboot service, I am sending to fluentd some dummy data:

```
// Local port 24224 is being forwarded to remote 24224 via oc port-forward command
private static FluentLogger LOG = FluentLogger.getLogger("app", "127.0.0.1", 24224);

Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
data.put("from", "userA");
data.put("to", "userB");

LOG.log("app", data);
```

which sends this piece of JSON data:

```
{"from":"userA","to":"userB"}
```

It is only working one out of ten times, apparently. Or seems to work two or three times and then brokes until I change the index. Not clear a pattern of behavior, actually.

When it does not work (most of the times), these are the logs in the fluentd pod:

```
2020-09-18 17:33:08.000000000 +0000 app.appaa: {"from":"userA","to":"userB"}
2020-09-18 17:33:37 +0000 [warn]: #0 dump an error event: error_class=ArgumentError error="log does not exist" location=nil tag="fluent.warn" time=2020-09-18 17:33:37.328180192 +0000 record={"error"=>"#<ArgumentError: log does not exist>", "location"=>nil, "tag"=>"app.appaa", "time"=>1600450388, "record"=>{"from"=>"userA", "to"=>"userB"}, "message"=>"dump an error event: error_class=ArgumentError error=\"log does not exist\" location=nil tag=\"app.appaa\" time=1600450388 record={\"from\"=>\"userAa\", \"to\"=>\"userBb\"}"}
2020-09-18 17:33:37.328180192 +0000 fluent.warn: {"error":"#<ArgumentError: log does not exist>","location":null,"tag":"app.appaa","time":1600450388,"record":{"from":"userA","to":"userB"},"message":"dump an error event: error_class=ArgumentError error=\"log does not exist\" location=nil tag=\"app.appaa\" time=1600450388 record={\"from\"=>\"userA\", \"to\"=>\"userB\"}"}
warning: 299 Elasticsearch-7.5.1-3ae9ac9a93c95bd0cdc054951cf95d88e1e18d96 "[types removal] Specifying types in bulk requests is deprecated."
```

Althoug the Elasticsearch pod does not show anything (I guess a matter of logging level), if I go to Elastic, I see this:

```
{
    "_index": "applogs-20200918",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "F0M2onQBB89nIri4Cb1Z",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
        "error": "#<ArgumentError: log does not exist>",
        "location": null,
        "tag": "app.app",
        "time": 1600449251,
        "record": {
            "from": "userA",
            "to": "userB"
        },
        "message": "dump an error event: error_class=ArgumentError error=\"log does not exist\" location=nil tag=\"app.app\" time=1600449251 record={\"from\"=>\"userA\", \"to\"=>\"userB\"}",
        "@timestamp": "2020-09-18T17:14:39.775332214+00:00",
        "@log_name": "fluent.warn"
    }
}
```

So it looks like the error comes from

> "Elastic: Argument Error: Log does not exist"

Did anyone face this error before?

Comment: Did you test this with `fluent-cat` command?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. No, I haven't. Do you consider that will make any difference? Among all the tries I am doing, I am attacking fluentd both from a local service and the same service running in a separated pod on OCP. As I am on Windows10, I am not very confident on installing fluent agent. But if you consider that it will make a difference, I'll try. Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome! That'll isolate the fluentd and elasticsearch pipleline. You can test it from the same machine where fluentd is running. `fluent-cat` should already be there. You don't have to install it separately on a different machine. It would help verify whether the client service has something to do with this or not; and, the pipeline is working.

Comment: Hi and thanks again for your advice. I did as you said, sending some requests to fluentd through fluent-cat and exact same behavior. So if I guess right, no problem with client or pipelin, right? Some kind of missconfiguration or bad availability of Elastic service :(

Comment: Can you share the command that you tried? And, the events are also `copy`ing to `stdout`. Are you seeing the logs on STDOUT? Are they correct?

Comment: Command: echo '{"message":"hello"}' | fluent-cat debug.log
Console:
2020-09-21 13:03:49.525380261 +0000 debug.log: {"message":"hello"}
2020-09-21 13:03:49 +0000 [warn]: #0 dump an error event: error_class=ArgumentError error="log does not exist" (...)}

Comment: So apparently fluentd does get correctly the message: 2020-09-21 13:03:49.525380261 +0000 debug.log: {"message":"hello"}
But then comes that uggly error: #0 dump an error event: error_class=ArgumentError error="log does not exist"

Comment: Right. `key_name log`. Can you try `echo '{"log":"hello"}' | fluent-cat debug.log`?

Comment: Relevant: https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/parser#key_name

Comment: That "log" in `log does not exist` error refers to that key to parse i.e. `log`. But, the event `{"from":"userA","to":"userB"}` does not contain such as key hence the `ArgumentError`.

Comment: Definitely that will do it. No error any more, but I'll have to study the documentation you referred to better understand how fluentd filter works. Anyway, the error is gone, so it definitely has all to do with that key_name parameter. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Yes, you should refer to the documentation for configuration. And, I would always use `fluent-cat` first to test things in isolation. Glad it helped. :)

Comment: Hi @Azeem. It would be awesome if you took a look to this other problem I got now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64669749/fluentd-is-not-filtering-as-intended-before-writing-to-elasticsearch. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The configuration of the parser in the filter i.e.

```xml
<filter *.**>
  @type parser
  key_name log    # << Look for key `log` in event
  # ...
</filter>
```

is looking for the key `log` which doesn't exist in this event:

```json
{"from":"userA","to":"userB"}
```

You need to use something like this:

```json
{"log":"... your log here..."}
```

You might need to escape `"` in there if you use quotations.

Relevant documentation: https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/parser#key_name